# Cannot create a directory inside external storage even though permissions are given

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I'm having issues creating a new directory on external storage in android studio. It might have to do something with permissions, but as far as I know, everything seems good.

What I want to do is:

> 1. Check if directory "/storage/emulated/0/Recordings" exists, if not - create the directory
> 2. Check if file "/storage/emulated/0/Recordings/tempFile.raw" exists, if exists - delete it
> 3. Create a file inside the directory using "new FileOutputStream(filename);"

Code im using (simplified):

```
String filepath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath();
//returns "/storage/emulated/0"
File file = new File(filepath,"Recordings");

if(!file.exists()){
   file.mkdirs();
}else{
   Log.w(TAG, "Didn't work");
}

fileName= "Recording #" + recordingNumber; //int recordingNumber = 1
recordingNumber++;
absolutePath = file.getAbsolutePath() + "/" + fileName + "tempFile.raw";

try {
   os = new FileOutputStream(absolutePath);
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
}
```

The error I'm getting:

`java.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/emulated/0/Recordings/tempFile.raw (No such file or directory)`

> Notice: There isn't "Didn't work" in logcat, meaning file.mkdirs() was executed.

Manifest permissions:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.REQUEST_IGNORE_BATTERY_OPTIMIZATIONS"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE"/>
```

Permissions:

[image: https://stackoverflow.com/image.jpg]

External storage on virtual device:

[image: https://stackoverflow.com/image.jpg]

Build.gradle:

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    buildToolsVersion "29.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.soundrecorder"
        minSdkVersion 22
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all you miss another permission:

> WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE

Moreover You have to explicitely ask for permission in your activity. Check this link:

https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting

```
if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(thisActivity,
        Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
        != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

    // Permission is not granted
    // Should we show an explanation?
    if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(thisActivity,
            Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)) {
        // Show an explanation to the user *asynchronously* -- don't block
        // this thread waiting for the user's response! After the user
        // sees the explanation, try again to request the permission.
    } else {
        // No explanation needed; request the permission
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(thisActivity,
                new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},
                MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_CONTACTS);

        // MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_CONTACTS is an
        // app-defined int constant. The callback method gets the
        // result of the request.
    }
} else {
    // Permission has already been granted
}
```

Comment: Gosh darn it. That was it. Must have been really tired and when adding a permission, accidently removed that one, or something along these lines and then didn't notice it wasn't there. Lesson learned though - double check everything, and then double check again. Thanks, man

Answer (score 2):

You need to add this in AndroidManifest.xml file in application tag `android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"` if you are running app on Android 10.

This is a temporary solution. From Android 11 [Scoped Storage](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage#scoped-storage) have to be used.

Comment: That wasn't the case but thanks for sharing. Cheers

Comment: You are welcome. Just for your information without this flag, your application will crash on devices with OS Android 10.
Also read this https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage#scoped-storage

Comment: thank you, this has been driving me crazy - was able to read from Samsung  & Huawei external storage but not Google Pixel (Android 10) - this resolved my problem!